# Run custom javascript from dynamicaly loaded innerHTML context

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, function, innerhtml

I have an HTML document

...

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

...

Then i dynamicaly load some context to #test div.

```
function change()
{
ws = document.getElementById(id);
str = '<script>function ttest(){window.alert("Yahoo!!!")}</script><select><option onclick="ttest();">1</option><option >2</option></select>';
ws.innerHTML = str;
}

window.onload = change();
```

When the page is loaded a custom script

```
<script>function ttest(){window.alert("Yahoo!!!")}</script>
```

doesnt work.

It works perfect when its put static without any innerHTML.
Also it works when its not a custom function.

How can i make my custom function work, when it was loaded dynamically using innerHTML or/and AJAX+innerHTML ?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work" ? What are you trying to do ?

Comment: I received a messafe that the function change doesnt exist.

Comment: But why would you inlude a javascript code like that ?

Comment: actually my code is a little bit more complex ))). This one is just to make a question and find a solution on how to run custom javascript which is loaded dynamically.
I am not afraid of sharing but there are too much text ....

Comment: try to write  str = '<scr' + 'ipt>function ttest(){window.alert("Yahoo!!!")}</scr' + 'ipt>';

Comment: When i look at my page (f12 mode) after the script is loaded i see that my script is actually loaded, I dont think that its the problem of some security standarts of w3c.
Its like the script should be loaded at the very begining in memory or something like cach, i dont know, and if its not it doesn`t work, browser doesn`t know about it .... It just my guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your script to the `document.head` via `createElement`. So something like this:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.innerHTML = "function ttest() { alert('Yahoo'); }";
document.head.appendChild(script)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works....!!!! But with one correction - document.getElementsByTagName('head') instead of document.head.